# mobx `makeAutoObservable` and inheritence

Tags: mobx

I have a base class `B` which is a mobx store and a derived class `A` which is **not** a mobx store.

As an example, it looks something like

```
class B {
  name = ""
  get firstName () {
    return this.name.split(" ")[0]
  }
  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
  }
}

class A extends B {
  // some other fields and methods
  constructor() {
    super(this)
  }
}
```

When I run the code `new A()` I get this error:

```
Error: [MobX] 'makeAutoObservable' can only be used for classes that don't have a superclass
```

This is because mobx correctly complains that it cannot automatically enumerate fields/methods of `A` in an object which is in a derived class `B` which doesn't have them as own properties, but they are up the prototypes chain instead.

But still, because I know that I want mobx to automatically go through class A's property (i.e. only one step up the prototype chain), I think that there should be a way for me to tell mobx that.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 4):

See this post:

[Is it possible to create inheritance between two mobx stores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695175/is-it-possible-to-create-inheritance-between-two-mobx-stores/65905836#65905836)

You have to do makeObservable and it should be in the later store.